# Problems deploying Java EE 6 application from netbeans to JBoss 6

Tags: jboss, java-ee-6, jax-rs, netbeans-7

I have a Java EE 6 application developed on Netbeans 7 and try to deploy it on a JBoss 6 instance. The application makes use of JAX-RS but I am not using any Jersey specific aspects, just standard JAX-RS features.

Deployments as a WAR fails because of some missing Jersey classes and deployment as an EAR fails due to `org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed`

Any idea what the cause of this might be?

What I do not want to do is disable RESTEasy in JBoss, I'd rather produce an application that runs on any Java EE 6 container without tweaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish silently adds Jersey JAX-RS packages to the build. If you uncheck the 'Package' checkbox in the project's lib configuration, the application is packaged without Jersey.

This makes sense, because after all, the target of the deployment might be a non-Java EE 6 container such as Tomcat.